# CakePHP 3 Find All Contain NULL data, displays nothing?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

### UPDATE

This is the join from the SQL after all the selects,

```
FROM users Users 
LEFT JOIN userinfos Userinfos ON Userinfos.id = (Users.userinfo_id) 
INNER JOIN offices Offices ON Offices.id = (Userinfos.office_id)
```

---

ok, I have a database (MySQL) setup with CakePHP 3 the users table has extended information held within another table.

This other table is also extended with an office / address information however this is set to NULL by default, so I want to include it in a 'contain' call but dose not return the user data when its empty?

So this is what I use currently,

```
  $UsersTable->find('all')
             ->contain(['Userinfos','Userinfos.Offices'])
             ->toArray();
```

But, Offices (office_id field in table Usersinfos) is not always set, however I still want it to return all the users even if they don't have an office set.

So I have tried,

```
  $UsersTable->find('all')
             ->contain([
                  'Userinfos',
                  'Userinfos.Offices'
              ])
             ->where(['Userinfos.office_id IS' => NULL])
             ->toArray();
```

Also,

```
  $UsersTable->find('all')
             ->contain([
                  'Userinfos',
                  'Userinfos.Offices' => 
                          function($q) {
                             return $q->where(['Userinfos.office_id IS' => NULL]);
                          }
              ])
            ->toArray();
```

The `$UsersTable` var is set to

```
   $UsersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
```

If I remove the `Userinfos.Offices` from the contain condition, then it returns all my current users. However, how can I call in this extra data/information so I have access to the Office information, e.g location name if that is set?

*I may not have explain myself clearly, please let me know if there is anything I can explain better, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL being generated by Cake?

Comment: I did but I did not see anything wrong with it, but I look at it in a bit more detail

Comment: What I don't understand is that this works, when the 'office_id' is set to something? that is what I can not figure out

Comment: What type of join is Cake using for the associates? Perhaps this needs changing for your requirement.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt if you'd show the generated SQL.

Comment: That was to be expected, an `INNER` join... as @drmonkeyninja said, check your associations, by default this would be a `LEFT` join.

Comment: Thanks. What I did was to move office into user-info table from users. However I did copy the 'belongsTo' from what Cake had baked for me. My SQL knowledge is a bit weak, think its time I had to extend it! - Please post this as an answer and I accept it.

Answer (score 6):

In cakePhp3.x in default when you bake a Model the join table is set to `INNER JOIN`. You would need to modify the model associations. You need to set the association to `LEFT JOIN`.

In your case if you look at 'UserinfosTable' in src/model/UserinfosTable make sure you are 'LEFT JOIN' ing the 'User' table or you can completely remove the 'joinType' because in default cakephp sets the `Contain` to 'LEFT JOIN'

```
class UserinfosTable extends Table
{

   public function initialize(array $config)
    {

      $this->belongsTo('Userinfos', [
            'foreignKey' => 'office_id',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT'
      ]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the `IS NULL` clause as a value instead of a key/value pair :

ex:
 `$UsersTable->find('all')->where(['Userinfos.office_id IS NULL'])`

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do NOT NULL (null is just `isNull(`

`->where(function ($exp, $q) {
    return $exp->isNotNull('office_id');
});`

Comment: It looks that one doesn't need $q parameter to be passed to the function: it is not used anywhere.